# IMAP (gmail?) returning incorrect UIDs to FETCH request

Tags: gmail, imap

I'm fiddling with IMAP in Python currently and have noticed the following (tested using single and multiple messages in a folder):

1. Select folder, "A" and fetch the UID of the message within
2. Move to another folder, "B", select that and fetch the new UID
3. Using the "B" UID, move the message back to folder "A"
4. Re-select folder "A" and fetch the new UID - as expected this gives a new UID for the message
5. Finally, issue a FETCH using the new UID from step 4

The issue is that in the 5th step the command executes OK - but the server returns a *different* UID to the one specified in the request (normally, but not always, a difference of 1)! For example:

```
LEFC12 UID FETCH 65 (FLAGS...)])
DEBUG:imapclient.imaplib:< * 3 FETCH (UID 64 ... {47}
```

The same happens with multiple messages - all of them are offset by the same amount.

If I have the process sleep for 20s (as in totally idle for 20s, if it retries every second it never comes back OK) - the fetch returns the correct UID fine. I'm not sure if this is a gmail or IMAP thing, any pointers/help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: here's all of the imapclient logs for the sequence above: https://gist.github.com/Fizzadar/37cb1fa808ffb6594326bba293f6daab. I have noticed that this isn't consistent - if you repeat the above steps twice over it *always* fails, but just the once it fails randomly (~50%, leading me to believe this is a gmail-specific issue).

Comment: Just to note - I'm considering "fixing" this by simply converting the incorrectly returned IDs to the requested ones as they do at least appear sequential/in-order.

Comment: Can you give the log of that whole flow?  This does sound like a bug on Gmail's IMAP server.  You also don't indicate whether you reselect folder A.

Comment: @Max I've added a log for the flow and updated the steps to reflect re-selecting folder A.

Comment: That is truly bizarre.  Looks definitely like a server bug to me.  If your library allows it, you may want to try UID MOVE instead, which Gmail indicates they have in their capabilities.